# Using certain values of an array?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Say I have an array defined like this :

```
Real, allocatable, dimension(:) :: h
N=5
allocate(h(N))
```

And then say i fill it with the values 1,1,1,1,1, and want to multiply the 0th element by something, how can I do this?

Note, it's in a loop, so it will do the 0th, then 1st, etc, so I can't just input it manually.

I tried h(0) * something, but got

```
unclassifiable statement at (1).
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please show the full statement that is the subject of the complaint.  You can't just write `h(0)*x` by itself, for example.  Also note that there is no element `h(0)`, the first being `h(1)`.

Comment: Please see [mcve], we need to see the complete error that is causing the error and the full error output.

Answer (score 2):

If you allocate an array in fortran as for example

```
allocate(h(N))
```

The array `h` has the elements `h(1)`,`h(2)`,`h(3)`,`h(4)`,`h(5)`.

Contrary to for example C++, array elements start at `1`. If you want to start at a different number, for example at `0`, you could allocate you array like this:

```
allocate(h(0:(N-1)))
```

The array now has the same length, but the elements are adressed as `h(0)`,`h(1)`,`h(2)`,`h(3)`,`h(4)`

Also, if you want to multiply a value of an array, you'd have to write something like

`h(i) = h(i) * 5.0d0`.

Comment: A simple out-of bounds error would not cause an `unclassifiable statement`

Comment: @VladimirF yes, but I wanted to explain the underlying problem the asker has, which was in my opinion not knowing how elements are numbered in arrays

Comment: I don't think that is his problem. Although it might be. The question is too unclear.

Comment: If you think the question is about how to give the lower bound of an array on allocation then there are other questions you could point to that this one duplicates.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. -1 from me.